Error occurring when clone from github to vs2022
I first wrote a c++ project in vs2022 and pushed it to github. I copied the URL of the project on github, pasted the URL into the clone of vs2022, saved it to an empty folder on drive E and opened it. When I clicked on a cpp file in the project, an error message was displayed saying that part of the path E://··· could not be found.
It's my first time using github to manage my codes. Please tell me what's wrong.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
